# getting permission denied for relation in potgresql

Tags: postgresql, backup, psql, backup-strategies

I connected to my db using this command

`psql -U bm_clients -d Bayne_DB`

and then I tried to run this command

```
Bayne_DB=> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA abcd TO bm_clients;
```

For which I received this error

```
ERROR:  permission denied for relation provider_seq
```

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `"Bayne_DB"` owns all affected objects.